# omnet epon https://omnetpp.org/download-items/EPON.html

Tags: omnet++

i am new to omnet. i want to use the epon module https://omnetpp.org/download-items/EPON.html
i can successfully make/build the inet,however i can not build the vlans project and the pon project.
here is the errors. i use the right version of omnet4.0 according to the installation

make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-debug/src/networklayer/ARP_Vlans.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/OMNET40/omnetpp-4.0/PON_0.8b/Vlans/src'
make: *** [src_dir] Error 2

i hope a master can save me

i just hope i can bulid the vlans project and the pon project successfully.